sourceCpp error: G__~1.EXE: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu++17'
I switched from R-3.6.3 to R-4.3.1 and R-4.4.1.
I tried to sourceCpp() some *.cpp which worked fine for R-3.6.3, but not for R-4.3.1 and R-4.4.1. The error is copied below.
Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2") is also not working for the newer R versions and gives the same error.

G__~1.EXE: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu++17'
using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64
project) 4.9.3' g++ -std=gnu++17
-I"C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG
-I"C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.4.1/library/Rcpp/include"
-I"C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/13/RtmpeWdnmC/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-1.0.12"
-I"c:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c filead48216f63d.cpp -o filead48216f63d.o
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu++17' make:
*** [C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-44~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:296:
filead48216f63d.o] Error 1
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir
= cacheDir,  :    Error 1 occurred building shared library

My version R version 4.4.1:

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_1.0.12
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] vctrs_0.6.5              zip_2.3.1                cli_3.6.3
rlang_1.1.4              rematch2_2.1.2           stringi_1.8.4
forcats_1.0.0            generics_0.1.3           glue_1.7.0
[10] colorspace_2.1-0         scales_1.3.0             fansi_1.0.6
RcppProgress_0.4.2       munsell_0.5.1            tibble_3.2.1
openxlsx_4.2.5.2         lifecycle_1.0.4          compiler_4.4.1
[19] dplyr_1.1.4              pkgconfig_2.0.3
RcppEigen_0.3.4.0.0      rstudioapi_0.16.0        paletteer_1.6.0
R6_2.5.1                 tidyselect_1.2.1         utf8_1.2.4
pillar_1.9.0             [28] parallel_4.4.1           magrittr_2.0.3
tools_4.4.1              RcppArmadillo_0.12.8.4.0

Someone has a clue?
Thanks

I cannot reproduce the error, Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2") works fine. Rcpp version ‘1.0.12’, R 4.4.1 on Windows 11.

Thanks for your comment. I guess there is a problem with rtools and corresponding settings regarding gnu, but I do not know how to change settings in this environment.

Maybe it's a PATH problem? Is rtools in your path variable? It can also be a version problem.

When you update R on Windows you must also update Rtools to the matching version.  Did you do that?

Ada's advice ultimately provided the solution. I was unaware that each R-4.x version requires a new Rtools installation. Although I needed Rtools44, I only had Rtools41 and other earlier versions installed. After installing the new Rtools version, it was correctly added to the path variable and set in RTOOLS44_HOME.
